# MySQL Select Stmt

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.0'
I want display user defined column when there is no data in select statement.

Example,
i want to display 'No records found' when there is no data in select statement.

Comment: Please change the title of your post for something more meaningful, and avoid using abbreviations (especially in the title).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [MySQL function ISNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for that (and then use it in your SELECT statement).
If the value is not necessarily NULL than you can use [the IF() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//control-flow-functions.html#function_if).